# Could not get json value while fetching all data from table using Python

Tags: python, json, django

I need to display the db table data in a tabular format but I could not find the data in JSON format using Python. I am providing my code below.

```
def view_book(request):
    """ This function is used for disply all the data """

    conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM booking_meeting ORDER BY id desc")
    all_value = cursor.fetchall()
    root = []
    json_output=json.dumps(all_value)
    print(json_output)
    for book in json_output:
        root.append(
            {'lname': book.location_name,
             'roomname': book.room_name,
             'seat': book.no_seat,
             'project': book.projector,
             'video': book.video,
             'from_date': book.from_date,
             'to_date': book.to_date})
    return render(request, 'booking/view_book.html', {'people': root})
```

Here I am getting the following error.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_book/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'location_name'
```

Here I need to append all data into JSON format so that I will be able to display it in table.

Comment: Why are you not using the orm?

Comment: Actually I have the requirement to use direct sql query for each db operation . Can you share your idea by post based on my needs.

Comment: On my phone at the moment, will do so as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: Ok can you share any reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to access the attributes **after** dumping them to JSON? JSON is a string, you cannot iterate through its properties without parsing.

Don't use JSON at all if you're not going to print it, render your data into JSON after you process it:

```
def view_book(request):
    """ This function is used for disply all the data """

    conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row  # needs this to create dictionaries
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM booking_meeting ORDER BY id desc")
    all_value = cursor.fetchall()
    root = []
    for book in all_value:
        book = dict(book)  # map it into a dict
        root.append(
            {'lname': book["location_name"],
             'roomname': book["room_name"],
             'seat': book["no_seat"],
             'project': book["projector"],
             'video': book["video"],
             'from_date': book["from_date"],
             'to_date': book["to_date"]})
    return render(request, 'booking/view_book.html', {'people': root})
```

Of course, if you want your `people` to hold a literal JSON turn it into JSON before returning:

```
    return render(request, 'booking/view_book.html', {'people': json.dumps(root)})
```

Comment: I did same as you but still `Exception Value: 
'tuple' object has no attribute 'location_name'` error.

Comment: @satya - that's because, by default, you get tuples of the results from `fetchall()`, not the actual dictionaries. Check the update above (the added line after `sqlite3.connect()`)

Comment: again its throwing the error `Exception Value: 
'sqlite3.Row' object has no attribute 'location_name'`.

Comment: because `print(all_value)` giving the data like this `[(3, u'cottage', u'2014-12-08T15:43:00', u'2014-12-08T15:43:00', u'5', u'Yes', u'No', u'2017-07-08 09:08', u'cuttuck'), (2, u'cottage', u'2014-12-08T15:43:00', u'2014-12-08T15:43:00', u'5', u'Yes', u'No', u'2017-07-08 08:51', u'cuttuck'), (1, u'room1', u'2014-12-08T15:43:00', u'2014-12-08T15:43:00', u'3', u'Yes', u'Yes', u'2017-07-08 07:48', u'Bhubaneswar')]`

Comment: Its throwing another error `Exception Value: 
Index must be int or string`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `all_value = cursor.fetchall()` then `all_value` is already a iterable of your records.

When you then execute `json_output=json.dumps(all_value)` you're converting it all to a string.

As a result, `for book in json_output:` will be iterating over a string.

You can simply skip the JSON conversion:

```
def view_book(request):
    """ This function is used for disply all the data """

    conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM booking_meeting ORDER BY id desc")
    all_value = cursor.fetchall()
    root = []
    for book in all_value:
        root.append(
            {'lname': book.location_name,
             'roomname': book.room_name,
             'seat': book.no_seat,
             'project': book.projector,
             'video': book.video,
             'from_date': book.from_date,
             'to_date': book.to_date})
    return render(request, 'booking/view_book.html', {'people': root})
```

Comment: I did as per you but same error `Exception Value: 
'tuple' object has no attribute 'location_name'`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you convert it into JSON object, it is treated as string by python. So while iterating, you are not getting 'book' as an object, rather as a string, and that is why you are getting this error. You can try the following approaches:

1) iterate over all_value rather than json_output.

2) iterate over json.loads(json_output). I am not sure if this would work.

3) It is not a good practice to write raw SQL queries, rather use django ORM. You might like to do this:

```
def view_book(request):
    """ This function is used for disply all the data """

    all_value = BookingMeeting.objects.order_by('-id')
    root = []
    for book in all_value:
        root.append(
            {'lname': book.location_name,
             'roomname': book.room_name,
             'seat': book.no_seat,
             'project': book.projector,
             'video': book.video,
             'from_date': book.from_date,
             'to_date': book.to_date})
    json_output=json.dumps(root)
    return render(request, 'booking/view_book.html', {'people': root})
```